# Fullcalendar fix week height with CSS / JS

Tags: fullcalendar

Example here:

http://jsbin.com/lonopu/edit?html,css,js,output

I have the calendar as a sidebar set at width: 260px and in fullcalendar set the height to 480px to avoid scrolling. How can I give the calendar a squarer appearance without scrolling? I just want to reduce the row heights, but

```
.fc-row .fc-week .fc-widget-content { height: 20px }
```

doesn't work, I guess it's because the calendar height is set dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try this :

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(){
  $('.fc-week.fc-widget-content.fc-rigid').attr('style', 'min-height: 3em');
}
```

instead of :

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(){
  $('.fc-row').css('min-height','10px'); 
  $('.fc-week, .fc-widget-content, .fc-rigid').attr('style','height: 10px');
},
```

Comment: Yes, just tried with Chrome and Firefox : [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/bolaqisoru/edit?js,output)

Comment: Could you try this one : [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/wubici/edit?css,js,output). The `eventAfterAllRender` may trigger too early.